# Можно ли реализовать аналог "mouse without border" для плейстейшен 4?

Tags: разработка-игр

стало интересно есть ли возможно реализовать управление playstation 4 с ноутбука? К примеру, чтобы, как в  "mouse without border", я мог подключится и переходить между экраном ps4 и ноутбука с помощью одной мыши или геймпада.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, чтобы получить Play Station SDK, нужно сначала стать их партнёром.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf А можно это реализовать по методам геймпада? То есть эмулируя его работу на компьютере